# Creating a unique identifier if a specific condition is met in Select-Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a problem with a query I wrote today. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT             
    t1.ID,
    t1.description,
    t1.plz,
    t1.street
FROM 
    Customer AS t1
JOIN 
    Customer ON t1.PLZ = Customer.PLZ
             AND t1.street= Customer.street
             AND t1.ID <> Customer.ID
ORDER BY 
    t1.plz, t1.street
```

I want my result to have a unique identifier for all values where t1.Strasse and t1.PLZ are the same as in other data records.

Like this:

| Identifier | ID | description | plz | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **001** | 1 | Grocery | 00001 | Main Street 1 |
| **001** | 4 | Juice Maker | 00001 | Main Street 1 |
| **001** | 5 | Bakery | 00001 | Main Street 1 |
| **002** | 6 | Bakery | 00001 | NotMain Street 2 |
| **003** | 10 | Grocery | 00001 | Beacon Street 101 |
| **003** | 11 | Juice Maker | 00001 | Beacon Street 101 |

My main problem is that I don't know how to create this identifier and how to increment it.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try `row_number()`.

Comment: What do you mean by a "unique identifier? A `uniqueidentifier`? If so, you can use `NEWID()`, however, incrementing a `uniqueidentifier` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. I didn't even know **uniqueidentifier**. I don't know the exact term for the thing I want and that is why I tried to visualize the concept in the table. Maybe a **group identifier** is a better word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` for the enumeration.  Also, I don't think you need a self-join:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.description, c.plz, c.street
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.street, t1.plz)
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY street, plz) as cntCustomer c 
      FROM Customer c2
     ) c
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY t1.plz, t1.street
```